# as3 if statment to check number range

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

can anyone tell me how to amend this so I can check if a number is in a range? 
Say for example 0-10 and 11-20. I've tried && and other things but can't get anything that works. 
I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. Thanks

```
stop();

value_enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release1);
function release1(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if ( Number(inputfield.text) > 0)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else if ( Number(inputfield.text) < 21)
    {
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a switch statement instead of multiple else if statements.
Its generally cleaner and more readable code.
It will also allow you add in more cases with ease.

```
stop();

value_enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release1);
function release1(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{

switch(true){
  case ( Number(inputfield.text) >=0 && Number(inputfield.text) <= 11):
    gotoAndStop(2);
    break;
  case ( Number(inputfield.text) >=10 && Number(inputfield.text) <= 21) :
    gotoAndStop(3);
    break;
  default:
    // inputfield.text value not in bounds 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//check the range 11-20
if (myNum >= 11 && myNum <= 20)
```

Comment: Ahh thanks strah I did seem to get it to work with:

stop();

value_enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release1);
function release1(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
if ( Number(inputfield.text) >=0 &&  Number(inputfield.text) <= 11)
{
gotoAndStop(2);
}
else if ( Number(inputfield.text) >=10 &&  Number(inputfield.text) <= 21)
{
gotoAndStop(3);
}

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a function ... and only cast one time.

```
function inRange(leftBoundary:Number, value:Number, rightBoundary:Number):Boolean
{
  return leftBoundary <= value && value <= rightBoundary;
}
```